# Intersections of unions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it generally true that $\bigcap_n A_n\cup B_n = \cap_nA_n \bigcup\cap_nB_n ?$

The intersection is on some indexing set and not necessarily finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not in general true. Here’s a fairly extreme counterexample. For $n\in\Bbb Z$ let $A_n=(n,\to)$ and $B_n=(\leftarrow,n]$. Then

$$\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb Z}(A_n\cup B_n)=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb Z}\Bbb R=\Bbb R\;,$$

but

$$\left(\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb Z}A_n\right)\cup\left(\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb Z}B_n\right)=\varnothing\cup\varnothing=\varnothing\;.$$

It’s not necessary to go to an infinite index set to find a counterexample, however: just let $A_0=\{0\}=B_1$ and $A_1=\varnothing=B_0$.

$$(A_0\cap A_1)\cup(B_0\cap B_1)=\varnothing\ne\{0\}=(A_0\cup A_1)\cap(B_0\cup B_1)\;.$$

What is true is that

$$\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i\right)\cup\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}B_i\right)\subseteq\bigcap_{i\in I}(A_i\cup B_i)\;.$$

Answer (score 3):

No. Consider $A_{2n} = B_{2n+1} = \varnothing, A_{2n+1} = B_{2n} = S$, with $S$ nonempty.

Comment: Thanks, it's been bugging me for an hour. How can I simplify $\bigcap_n A_n\cup B_n$ then?

Comment: In general, you can't. You would e.g. need all $A_n$ to be the same $A$, see [here](https://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Intersection_Distributes_over_Union).

Comment: What if $A_n \cap B_n = \emptyset?$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question :(.

Comment: yeah. me neither, i think i'll go to sleep now. thanks anyway for clearing the confusion.